# Is it possible to tell if a Git hook has been bypassed?

Tags: git

Say I push to a remote:

```
git commit --no-verify -a -m stuff
git push --no-verify origin some-branch
```

When somebody pulls that branch can they see that this commit bypassed two hooks?

Answer (score 3):

No, they cannot see if you bypassed the hook.

For this reason, implement the crucial checking scripts server side, and reject any pushes containing "bad" commits